# Symfony 3.4 very slow after upgrading from Symfony 2.1

Tags: symfony

I have upgraded an application from Symfony 2.1 to Symfony 3.4. When I test the new app in localhost, it works perfectly and fast, even faster 
than the previous application. But, when I push the application on the server, I have some huge loading times of 2 minutes for the 
new app, while the app under Symfony 2.1 loads within 1 second on his server.

The database parameters are the same in the two versions, and I have been struggling for many days to figure out what's the problem. And especially, 
I don't know if it's a problem with the application or with the server.

For more precision, here are the details on the two apps :

**Before upgrading :**

PHP 5.3

Symfony 2.1

Windows Server 2012 on VM

XAMPP

MySQL

Loading time : about 1 second

composer.json file :

```
{
    "name" : "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license" : "MIT",
    "type" : "project",
    "description" : "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-0" : {
            "" : "src/"
        }
    },
    "require" : {
        "php" : ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony" : "2.1.13",
        "doctrine/orm" : ">=2.2.3,<2.5-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "1.1.*",
        "twig/extensions" : "1.0.*@dev",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle" : "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle" : "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle" : "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle" : "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle" : "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle" : "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle" : "1.2.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle" : "1.1.*",
        "kriswallsmith/assetic" : "1.1.*@dev",
        "besimple/sso-auth-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "besimple/soap" : "0.2.*@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "~1.3",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle" : "2.1.*",
        "sonata-project/cache-bundle" : "2.1.*",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle" : "2.1.*",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle" : "2.1.*@dev",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle" : "2.1.*",
        "noiselabs/nusoap-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/intl-bundle" : "2.1.*",
        "whiteoctober/breadcrumbs-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories" : [{
            "type" : "package",
            "package" : {
                "name" : "nusphere/nusoap",
                "version" : "0.9.5",
                "dist" : {
                    "url" : "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/nusoap/nusoap/0.9.5/nusoap-0.9.5.zip",
                    "type" : "zip"
                },
                "autoload" : {
                    "classmap" : [
                        "lib/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "scripts" : {
        "post-install-cmd" : [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd" : [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "extra" : {
        "symfony-app-dir" : "app",
        "symfony-web-dir" : "web",
        "branch-alias" : {
            "dev-master" : "2.1-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

**After upgrading :**

PHP 7.2

Symfony 3.4

Windows Server 2016 on VM

XAMPP

MySQL (the same database is called in the two apps)

Loading time : 2 minutes

composer.json file :

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" },
        "files": [ "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php" ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "besimple/sso-auth-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "^1.6",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.6",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.48",
        "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "^3.0",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.8",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0",
        "whiteoctober/breadcrumbs-bundle": "^1.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.2.6"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "3.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Have you any idea why there is such a loading time in the new app ?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT :**

Hi @habibun, and thank you for your answer.

Here is below a picture of the performance in the profiler :

[Performance in the Profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/at67V.png)

The problem seems to be dued to the line "controller" that takes 105 seconds. Is there a way to reduce the loading time of this line ?

Also, can you tell me how I can browse config.php on Symfony 3.4 ? Which command should I use ? Sorry if I ask dumb questions, I'm newbie on Symfony.

Comment: just open console goto network tab and see work's going on and also browse **config.php** for Symfony recommendation.

Comment: Have you warmed up the cache before? Is the second attempt to load your page still slow?

Comment: Hi @habibun , thanks a lot for your answer. I have edited my question with a picture of the performance in the profiler. Also, can you tell me how I can browse config.php on Symfony 3.4 ? Which command should I use ?

Comment: You can see in profiler that it's DB issue. As doctrine is taking 97 seconds. Check doctrine profiler and queries what are taking so long, then optimize them.

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase , the result is the same in both cases : after clearing the cache and during a second or third attempt. In each case, the loading time is very slow.

Comment: I would suggest making a new hello world 3.4 project and uploading to your server.  That will tell you if the delay is somehow to due to 3.4 itself or if you have something else going on.  From there you might add a very simple query since the database seems to part of the problem.  If nothing else, you will learn quite a bit about Symfony.  Kind of impressive that a "newbie" was able to move an app from 2.1 to 3.4 in the first place.  Quite a jump.

Comment: Finally, I found the issue. It was a different parameter between the two database configurations, that I didn't see before. So now, the loading time is normal. Thanks to you all for your answers and your time. This post can be closed.